# Know the revision I did a checkout from a given Repo

Tags: svn, version-control

I have made a checkout some time ago from my Subversion Repo to my hard-drive.

At the time I didn't take notice of what revision I did checkout from and I'd like to know this now.

Is it possible? Better yet, I'd like to also which was the last update I made.

Is that info saved in some way or is it lost?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
svn info
```

prints

```
Path: .
URL: svn://svn.mplayerhq.hu/mplayer/trunk
Repository Root: svn://svn.mplayerhq.hu/mplayer
Repository UUID: b3059339-0415-0410-9bf9-f77b7e298cf2
Revision: 33161
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: cehoyos
Last Changed Rev: 33161
Last Changed Date: 2011-03-30 10:54:55 -0400 (Wed, 30 Mar 2011)
```

`cat .svn/entries` has most of this at the top of it

Answer (score 1):

you can have some informations by using the `svn info` command. It gives you the last modification date and the revision of your working copy. But i don't know if it is possible to retrieve the checkout date...

Comment: Thanks. I don't need the checkout date, only the revision!